# What is the replacement of memory.swappiness file in cgroups v2

Tags: swap, cgroups

I'm currently migrating from cgroups v1 to cgroups v2. And I can't find the memory.swappiness file that I used in cgroups v1. There are only the following files concerning swap

```
memory.swap.current
memory.swap.events
memory.swap.high
memory.swap.max
```

but each of them has nothing to do with the swappiness parameter, according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html). I couldn't find any information about the file memory.swappiness in cgroups v2, only about `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` file and vm.swappiness parameter in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file. Does it mean that there is no possibility to set the swappiness using cgroups v2?

OS: Debian 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That’s right, with cgroups v2, swappiness can only be controlled globally. Tejun Heo (who designed and implemented cgroups v2) [has given the following rationale](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1005):

> It’s not very clear what swappiness encodes. A lot of it is compared to file-backed IOs, how [un]favorable IOs for anonymous memory are considering their inherently higher randomness. As such, it’s more a function of the underlying hardware than workloads. Also, the implementation wasn’t quite right either – iirc, the behavior would differ depending on who’s reclaiming.

In practice, swappiness is more about the I/O balance in the system, which is typically a property of the system’s storage rather than individual workload behaviour.

cgroups v2 provides other settings which can be used [to control memory usage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#memory-interface-files), often in more appropriate ways than swappiness: thresholds can be set to prevent reclaim entirely (`memory.min`), try to minimise reclaim (`memory.low`), and limit swap usage (`memory.swap.max` and in extreme cases `memory.swap.high`).